# How to get and set value in the switch-case statement

Tags: java, menu, switch-statement

I want to make a simple menu with 3 choices:

'Create new employee', 'Display all employees' and 'Quit' in a Employee Manager(code below) but it was not successful(compiling error).

BlueJ editor cannot realize the object 'm', 's' and 'l' in the 'case 2' statement. Is there anyway to get the value of the object in the 'case 1' and use them in the 'case 2'? Thanks a lot!

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int ch;
        do{
            System.out.println("EMPLOYEE MANAGER\n");
            System.out.println("1. Create new employees\n");
            System.out.println("2. Display all employees\n");
            System.out.println("3. Quit\n");
            System.out.print("Your choice: ");

            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
            ch = input.nextInt();

            switch(ch){
                case 1: System.out.println("== CREATE NEW EMPLOYEES ==");
                    System.out.println();
                    Manager   m = new Manager();
                    Scientist s = new Scientist();
                    Labourer  l = new Labourer();
                    m.newManager();
                    s.newScientist();
                    l.newLabourer();
                    System.out.println();
                    break;

                case 2: System.out.println("==  PREVIEW  EMPLOYEES  ==");        
                    System.out.println();
                    m.display();
                    s.display();
                    l.display();
                    System.out.println();
                    System.out.println();
                    break;
                case 3: System.exit(0);
                default: System.out.println("Invalid choice!");
            }
        } while(ch >= 1 && ch <=4);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

They are local to block, declare them out of switch block

```
Manager   m = new Manager();
Scientist s = new Scientist();
Labourer  l = new Labourer();

switch(){...}
```

This answers your question well, but I would like to add few more details

if you don't put brackets with case block like

```
 switch(i){
   case 1:
    String str="abc";
    System.out.println(str);
   case 2:
     // it will give you compile time error
     //duplcate local variable str
     String str="abc";

    }
```

then this `str` instance is visible in other case blocks as well

Comment: I dont get why you create the objects when OP wants to create them in option 1, not before.

Comment: Thanks, Jigar! But when I switch to case 2, all the values are null. They all works before I add the 'simple menu'.

Comment: Didn't get you, could you please update the question and notify us

Comment: You're much better off 1) grouping the "things you're doing" into separate methods, 2) making the "data you're using" "member data" and, most importantly, making it a real "class" (instead of relying on "static main ()".  Even for a simple case like this.  IMHO...

Comment: PS: for any serious Java development, I'd strongly recommend an IDE like NetBeans or Eclipse over a teaching tool like BlueJ.  Again: IMHO...

Answer (score 1):

Q: Is there anyway to get the value of the object in the 'case 1' and use them in the 'case 2'?

A: No.  The whole point of a case block is "either-or".

If you want to do "something" based on "something else", then you'll need two separate control structures.

EXAMPLE:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test
{
    Manager m = null;
    Scientist s = null;
    Labourer  l = null;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
       Test test = new Test().doIt ();
    }

    private void doIt () {
       int ch;
       do{
          System.out.println("EMPLOYEE MANAGER\n");
          System.out.println("1. Create new employees\n");
          System.out.println("2. Display all employees\n");
          System.out.println("3. Quit\n");
          System.out.print("Your choice: ");

          Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
          ch = input.nextInt();

          switch(ch) {
          case 1: 
              System.out.println("== CREATE NEW EMPLOYEES ==");
              getEmployees ();
              break;

          case 2: 
              System.out.println("==  PREVIEW  EMPLOYEES  ==");
              previewEmployees ();
              break;

          case 3: 
              System.exit(0);
              break;

          default: 
              System.out.println("Invalid choice!");
       }
    } while(ch >= 1 && ch <=4);
 }

 private void getEmployees () {
    System.out.println();
    m = new Manager();
    s = new Scientist();
    labourer  l = new Labourer();
    m.newManager();
    s.newScientist();
    l.newLabourer();
    System.out.println();
 }

 private void previewEmployees () {
    ...
```

}

Comment: Thanks! It seems to work but I have an error: 'incompatible types - found void but expected Test' in the main block. –

Answer (score 0):

Define your objects m, s and l in a broader scope outside the switch. Also, initialize your objects with null value and validate them before using.

```
Manager   m = null;
Scientist s = null;
Labourer  l = null;
do{
    //your code here....
        switch(ch) {
        case 1:
            m = new Manager();
            //the rest of your code here...
            break;
        case 2:
            if (m != null) {
                m.display(); //and so on
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Luiggi! But I want to set the value in the op1, then get them and display in the op2. Is it possible?

Comment: @K.Dam yes, I've already updated my post, I forgot you were declaring the objects inside the loop, and they should be in a broader scope, like outside the `do` or as attributes of your class.

Comment: I've tried your code but it seems to have nothing in the op2. :( Maybe I have some problem with my other class... But thanks for the help! I'll keep in mind your tips! Good day to you!